# Как получить доступ к переменной внутреннего класса из другого пакета?

Tags: java, доступ

Как в классе `C` получить доступ к переменной `str` внутреннего класса  `PubInnerClass`, которая лежит в классе `А`, если она `protected`?

Вот класс А:

```
package Trash.ModAccess.A;

public class ClassA {

    public class PubInnerClass {

        protected   String str="word";

    }

}
```

Вот класс C:

```
package Trash.ModAccess.C;

import Trash.ModAccess.A.ClassA;

public class ClassC extends ClassA {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: мне просто нужно вывести на экран str в классе С

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас классы `ClassA` и `ClassC` находятся в разных пакетах, чтобы был доступ к строке `str` из другого пакета, она должны быть `public`, либо вам нужно использовать `Reflection API`.

```java
ClassA.PubInnerClass pubInnerClass = new ClassA().new PubInnerClass();
Field field = pubInnerClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("str");
field.setAccessible(true);
String str = (String)field.get(pubInnerClass);
System.out.println(str);
```

Вывод: `word`.

Comment: Не помогло, вставил твой код в  IDE ругается, что str   protected.

Comment: Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Спасибо, я подумал, что все-таки можно достучаться без рефлекшн до переменных внутреннего класса из другого пакета.